# i/o file writing code error

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

Following is the code which works fine when it is in main() method. Compiles and gives .jasper file as an output

```
package com;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;

public class JasperCompile {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JRException {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:\\temp.jrxml", "C:\\temp.jasper");
    }
}
```

But when I embed following line from main() method to servlet's doGet method then it doesn't work

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:\\temp.jrxml", "C:\\temp.jasper");
```

Following is the stack trace.

```
Jan 7, 2014 4:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [JasperReportsBrowserDemoServlet] in context with path [/PDFReports] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.addSetProperties(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/StringV
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsXmlHandler.addListRules(ComponentsXmlHandler.java:117)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsXmlHandler.configureDigester(ComponentsXmlHandler.java:104)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.addComponentRules(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:514)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.configureDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:493)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1324)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:207)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:172)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:108)
at com.JasperReportsBrowserDemoServlet.createJRXML(JasperReportsBrowserDemoServlet.java:136)
at com.JasperReportsBrowserDemoServlet.doGet(JasperReportsBrowserDemoServlet.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 4:23 PM
```

what difference it makes when we write code in main() method and server side ?

Comment: What is the version of JasperReport?

Comment: If version of JasperReport is incorrect then why am I getting output when it is running in main() method. Same jar files I am using for both program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Apache Commons Digester is incorrect. Review all dependencies of JasperReport.

Comment: If  Apache Commons Digester  is incorrect then why am I getting output when it is running in main() method. Same jar files I am using for both program.

Comment: If possible an error in your classpath (duplicate jars or similar problem)

Comment: Your server is using other jar of Apache Commons Digester when your invoke as servlet. For a fast test, put your libraries into lib folder in your web proyect and test again.